# excel file created with EPPlus, displaying message while opening that file has to repair, click yes

Tags: excel, epplus

After click yes, it is showing:

`Repaired Records: String properties from /xl/sharedStrings.xml part(Strings)`

`Repaired Records: Table from /xl/tables/table.xml part(Table)`

I think there is no problem in code, but still here is my code what I am using to create Excel.

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(newFile)) {
     ExcelWorksheet worksheet = null;
     worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(dataToExcelExport.TableName);
     worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataToExcelExport, true, 
                                             OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.None);
     worksheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
     worksheet.Column(4).Width = 55.00;
     worksheet.Column(4).Style.WrapText = true;
     worksheet.Cells[1, 1, worksheet.Dimension.End.Row, 3].AutoFitColumns();
     package.Save();
     worksheet.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me.  Maybe post more of your code. Or post the file somewhere.  Check the content of the data table - since it is complaining about the string store see if there is anything that may need escaping.

Comment: Want is in `dataToExcelExport`?  Yes, your code looks OK....

Comment: I encountered the same issue when using EPPlus and exporting a large GeoJson or KML geometry string to Excel. As soon as I removed this part of the data the issue went away. Currently investigating if I can work-around the issue. Raised the following issue against project - https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/15395

Answer (score 12):

When I encountered this issue while using EPPlus it was because I was trying to exceed limits imposed by Excel.

In my case I was trying to insert more than 32,767 characters in a cell.

Limits for Excel are given here:
https://support.office.com/en-MY/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-16c69c74-3d6a-4aaf-ba35-e6eb276e8eaa